# Bootstrap3 dropdown menu toggle collapse div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to get the Bootstrap3 nav dropdown to trigger a collapsible div at the same time it displays the dropdown - basically to 'simulate' a fullwidth subnav bar:

```
$('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
    $('#collapseExample').slideDown('normal');
});
$('.dropdown').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
    if (!$('div.dropdown').hasClass('open')) {
        $('#collapseExample').slideUp('normal');
    }
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myRgbQ

I have 'almost got it working but it behaves strangely when there is already one subnav open...

I'm sure it would be a quick fix, but I'm stumped! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$('#collapseExample').collapse(true);   
$('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
        $('#collapseExample').slideDown('normal');
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown();
    });
    $('.dropdown').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
        if (!$('div.dropdown').hasClass('open')) {
            $('#collapseExample').slideUp('normal');
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Afraid that doesn't work, the collapse is initially open now (probably an easy fix) but it still behaves wierdly when opening a 2nd dropdown :( thanks tho!